# How do I update Boolean status of checked boxes in react?

Tags: reactjs

I pulled data from API and represented on a table, I need to select items in the list and send to another API after selection. But I'm struggling as to toggling the status before submission. Here the code below...

```
function AllReferral() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  //submitHandler///
  const handleClick = (user) => {
    let mainServices = user?.services.map((element) => {
      return {
        serviceName: element?.label,
        serviceCode: element?.value,
        price: element?.price,
        status: checked,
      };
    });

    const params = JSON.stringify({
      services: mainServices,
      note: notes,
    });

    Axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      data: params,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        Secondary Services(Referral):
        {user?.services?.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col">Service Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Service Code</th>
                  <th scope="col">Service Price</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {user?.services?.map((item, index) => (
                <tbody key={index}>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input
                        name="serviceName"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={checked}
                        onChange={(e) => setChecked(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </td>

                    <td>{item?.label}</td>

                    <td>{item?.value}</td>

                    <td>
                      <span>
                        &#8358;
                        {item?.price}
                      </span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              ))}
            </table>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I am doing something wrong in the implementation and would appreciate any help such that any item selected from the list would have a status of true and non selected would be false

Comment: What happens if you do onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)} instead of onChange={(e) => setChecked(e.target.value)}?

Comment: @Leo Santos it returns all status FALSE

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={checked}
  onChange={()=> setChecked(prevState => !prevState)}
/>
```